# vim delete lambda variable and block

Tags: vim, vsvim

I have cursor at first `t` and I want to delete all this code from `t` to `};\n` without lines counting.

How can I achieve it? Is there cleaner way than <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>?

```
tabControl.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    ...
};
```

If it matters, this is C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way is probably `Vj%d`, but see below for shorter options that work in many cases.

- `V` = enter [Visual line mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#linewise-visual).
- `j` = go down one character.
- `%` = go to matching brace.
- `d` = delete the selection.

Alternatively, if there are no empty lines in the lambda, but there is an empty line after it, I would use `d}` (`}` is go to 'end of paragraph', which usually means the next empty line) or `dap` (neumonic: 'delete all paragraph', works from anywhere in the 'paragraph', assuming your function has empty lines before and after). `dap` is really useful for deleting short blocks of code.

Note also that your solution will not work if there is a nested lambda terminated by `};`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a cleaner and simple way to get the desired output in 3 steps:

**1**. First click <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> in normal mode to delete the first line :

```
tabControl.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
```

As a result the line below will be moved up where the cursor is placed

```
{
```

Notice that the cursor must be placed in the opening **{** so you can use the `%` command as you will see in the 2 step

**2**. Type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>%</kbd> (for **selection**) so you can be sure that the exact block **{}** will be selected

```
{
    ...
};
```

Note: it is **`V`** (**Uppercase**) not **`v`** there is a difference between the two commands

> **v**                Start Visual mode per character.
>
> **V**                Start Visual mode linewise.

**3**. Type then <kbd>d</kbd> : to delete the selected block

so the sequence will be <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

you can also check the help to see what `%` really do by typing in the command line

```
:help %
```

> **%** :                    Find the next item in this line after or under
>                           the
>                           cursor and jump to its match. |inclusive| motion.
>                           Items can be:
>                           ([{}])          parenthesis or (curly/square) brackets

I tried to underline some useful commands but if you understand exactly what the **`V`** and **`%`** do you can select directly the whole block you would like to delete or to modify

Comment: Are you sure you can't just do `d%`?

Comment: the `%` is only useful if you are sure that the cursor is above one of these characters { } [ ] ( )  and if you read the question you will notice it is not the case. So `d%` will do nothing !

Comment: Oh, my understanding was that it would seek forward to the nearest valid character, then do its magic. I could have sworn I'd seen that behavior... somewhere, though I can't find it anymore. thanks!

Comment: @QPaysTaxes It will do that, but only for characters on the same line.